# Problem starting OneLogin Sample node app

Tags: onelogin

I signed up a developer account on OneLogin. I checked out the repo "https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-node/tree/master/1.%20Auth%20Flow" to start the sample app. After following the instructions when I do "npm start" it does not start the app. No error also shows up on the console.
The console shows only this:

> node ./bin/www

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the repo https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-node it contains several different sample projects.

You need to ensure that you move into the directory the sample that you want to try and install required packages before starting.

e.g.

```
> git clone https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-node.git
> cd onelogin-oidc-node
> cd 1.\ Auth\ Flow/
> npm install
> npm start
```